# Where do the Millennium Falcon dice end up?

Tags: star-wars, the-last-jedi

In *The Last Jedi*, we see Luke take the gold dice from the cockpit of the Millennium Falcon before reminiscing with Artoo. Later, he seems to give them to Leia on Crait, but it's eventually revealed that those are a Force projection.

Is there any evidence of what happened to the actual set of dice? Did Luke replace them in the cockpit before Rey and Chewbacca went back to the Resistance, or are they still on Ahch-To?

Comment: We don't know. If we knew, it would have ruined the 'reveal' that they aren't real.

Comment: Unless they show up either subtly enough that you wouldn't notice them on first watch, or after that reveal. I went looking and didn't see them, but maybe I missed something...

Comment: I'm just gonna have a quick look at the end of the film before I VTC as per the "Future Works policy". It's strongly likely that they'll show up in the next film

Comment: Maybe the dice never left the Falcon?

Comment: @Boolean Those were not the dice you were looking for anyways. Move along...

Answer (score 2):

The dice were removed from the cockpit long before *The Last Jedi*.  Their last chronological appearance in the original trilogy was in the "Star Wars Holiday Special," which reused some footage of Han and Chewie in the Millennium Falcon that was shot for the first movie.  You can see from this wide shot of the ship's cockpit from *The Empire Strikes Back* that they are not present.

[image: Cockpit]

Nor are they there when Lando is flying the ship in *Return of the Jedi.*

In *The Last Jedi*, the dice were imaginary all along.  Luke was just thinking back to the ship as it was at the time of his first adventure.

Comment: Do you have any evidence they weren’t put back in again or that they actually were never real beyond this? It seems like a massive jump to make.