# How could Luke physically hold the dice and touch Leia?

Tags: star-wars, the-last-jedi

In *The Last Jedi* (2017), when Luke projects himself onto the planet where the rebels are, he first meets up with Leia and gives her Han's dice and kisses her on the forehead.

How was he able to do this?  I mean he was a projection after all and everything just passed through him as later seen when he fights Kylo Ren and the AT-AT's.

This is only possible if Leia had already realized that Luke isn't actually there.

Comment: Luke's projection was basically as physical as he wanted it to be. That's what made his feat so impressive. Rey and Kylo could do something similar due to their unique link, but only with each other.

Comment: TLJ already shows physical objects being passed from one Force user to another.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Where do the Millennium Falcon dice end up?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/190873/where-do-the-millennium-falcon-dice-end-up)

Comment: it partially does, so wait I am gonna have to reframe the question

Comment: moreover your link says that the dices were his imagination, so how was leia able to hold them?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The dice are part of the illusion. This is made clear in a later scene when Kylo Ren storms the Resistance base on Crait and picks up the dice. They disappear in his hand:

[image: Gif of illusory dice disappearing in Kylo Ren's hand]

Leia does already know that Luke isn't there:

> "No one's ever really gone," he said quietly, leaning forward to kiss her on the forehead as he took her hands in his.
>
> When they touched, she immediately understood. A slight smile played at the corners of her mouth, and her eyes shone with the secret the two of them now shared.
>
> (*The Last Jedi: Expanded Edition*, page 357 of Kindle edition)

As for how the illusion can be selectively permeable, it seems to just be part of the power. Luke can create solid objects and touch people, while also letting laser blasts and the salt on the ground pass through the illusion.